# File upload error handling in spring mvc form having large data

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

I have a form which has multiple fields including two fields for file upload. Currently I have single submit for whole form. Problem with this approach is that whenever there is any error in the form (in any of the field) my file upload fields became empty. I am aware that we cannot re-populate the upload field data due to security reason. Kindly let me know the best alternative for this as this is functionality is very frustrating for users.